# Read a file on httpd configured server with HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, html, httpd.conf

I am developing a web based application that displays web page on client server based on a xml file from the web server that is configured with httpd.
I am new to httpd and need guidance on how to code HTML page that reads xml file from web server with httpd, how to code the file path in HTML and how to call the httpd to access the file with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to [map a URI to a filesystem location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html).

Assume your hostname is *example.com* and your have a file `foo.xml`, here is what you need to do:

1. Put `foo.xml` in server's directory, say `/var/www/xmls`
2. Edit httpd.conf, set `DocumentRoot /var/www`
3. Create index.html in `/var/www`
4. In `index.html` add link `http://example.com/xmls/foo.xml`
5. start httpd service

Now if you open http://example.com, you will see your index.html page. If you click the link you just added you should be able to download/view `foo.xml`.

Note: the runner of `httpd` must have `r+x` permissions on `www` and `xml` directories.